# I am unable to write to MS Access Database using pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access

I am unable to write this df into the access table.
What am I not doing right?

```
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Database1.mdb;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Index_data;'
dfins = pd.read_sql(SQL, cnxn)
for index, row in dfins.iterrows():
    with cnxn.cursor() as crsr:
        crsr.execute('select * from df')
conn.commit()
```

[image: Error Datasource not found]

Answer (score 1):

You probably have not installed ODBC driver for MS Access, or its name

`"Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)"`

don't agree with the string used in your program — for newer versions of Microsoft Access it is

`"Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)"`.

So verify its name, or install it:

1. Open *Control Panel*, select *Administrative Tools*, then *ODBC Data Sources*.
2. New window will open up. Select *“User DSN”* tab.

Then verify the driver name, or install an appropriate Microsoft Access Driver — see for example [Steps to create a New ODBC Connection on Windows 10](https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-create-a-new-odbc-connection-on-windows-10/).